# Can I add comments to a pip requirements file?

Tags: python, comments, pip

I'd like to add comments for a few packages in a pip requirements file. (Just to explain why that package is on the list.) Can I do this?

I'm imagining something like

```
Babel==0.9.5 # translation
CherryPy==3.2.0 # web server
Creoleparser==0.7.1 # wiki formatting
Genshi==0.5.1 # templating
```

Answer (score 567, accepted):

Sure, you can, just use `#`

[`pip` docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/requirements-file-format/):

> A line that begins with `#` is treated as a comment and ignored. Whitespace followed by a `#` causes the `#` and the remainder of the line to be treated as a comment.

Comment: To anyone visiting from google: note the important word **whitespace** here. If you don't have whitespace, e.g. "beautifulsoup4#==4.8.2", the characters after the # will not be treated as a comment.